# Loading random objects from a huge (>200MB) array file without loading the entire array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I am building a static Angular website whose data is based on 1000 random objects from a huge array that contains more than 200,000 JSON objects. I am storing the huge array of JSON objects in text form somewhere online (like Github or Dropbox), and the text file size is larger than 200MB. It's obviously not an option to load all the data in the website due to performance concerns, but I also do not want to use a database as I am building a static website. How do I only load randomly 1000 objects out of the 200,000 objects without loading the entire array?

Comment: Lots of static sites use cloud based databases or data storage. Your approach is not practical

Comment: This does not seem to be possible without some server side program. That is just the way HTTP works.

Comment: JSON is a serialized format,. it has no concept of random access..  Your best be might be to divide this JSON into multiple smaller JSON files.

Comment: Write a parser for json yourself in JS (or find one online) and make it so that (as it goes) it only keeps elements x-through-y in the root array. It will download all the json (as text, thats just how http be) but it wont load them (as objects). Without serverside code, this is the only way (obviously serverside execution is the way to do what you want. But I like to say nothing is *impossible*)

Comment: @Hashbrown `It will download all the json (as text, thats just how http be)`  Actually HTTP can do ranges, depending on the format of the JSON, it might be a bit tricky though to anchor to a logical start / end for decoding..

Comment: Using this, you could even hook it into the xhttprequest and get it to cancel after reading the 1000 you want, possibly even not dowloading it all. But the benefit there would be negligible. Keith's idea fixes both these issues much more simply if you have access to the server with this json "somewhere online".

Comment: @keith that's amazing! I hadn't heard of that. Would only work if every element in the array has a predictable [serialised] size, though

Comment: @Hashbrown  Yes, could be tricky.  I suppose it depends on how complicated the JSON structure is.  Also it does require the Server to be able to do ranges, most do nowadays, eg.  Here on stackoverflow, the header returned is.  `accept-ranges: bytes`, this mean it can do ranged downloading.  But the OP will just need to double check were he's hosting, just in case.

Comment: mmm, actually thinking about this a little bit more, if the OP can pre-process his 200meg JSON file, and from this create a sort of Indexed.Json file, were it basically store's the starting & ending offset of each JSON record, & if were the OP is hosting can handle ranges, using the https ranged download should work nicely..

Comment: I'm just hosting it on Github. I'll double check whether they support ranges!

Comment: You are essentially describing a file system. Just continue doing it then, ex. `import xxx` or `require()`.

Comment: @Keith I get it to work when the start of byte range is 0, but it gives me an error when the start range isn't 0. I opened a new question regarding this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750110/http-range-request-doesnt-work-if-the-start-range-isnt-zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could attempt to download only the first partial chunk of the file and try to use that.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

You would use the Angular's HTTP service to make a `GET` request, but would add `Range: bytes=0-1023` to the headers. Where `0-1023` defines the number of bytes you would like to fetch (using a start and end range).

If the server supports this feature, then you'll have to clean up the string JSON that is fetched from the server. Since the JSON will be cut-off before it's complete.

Without me knowing what the structure of the JSON is. It's difficult to say if this is a practical solution, but if it's an array of JSON objects. You could try to find a byte range that ends on an array separator `,` character and just append `]` to the end of the string.

If you need random parts of the file. You would make multiple `GET` requests for different partial chunks, and then try to clean the JSON so that it's valid.

Comment: I tried your method and it seems to only work when the range starts from 0, and it gives me an error when I put, for instance, bytes=1-1023. I open a new question for this specific problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750110/http-range-request-doesnt-work-if-the-start-range-isnt-zero.