# HTTP range request doesn't work if the start range isn't zero

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, http, github

Here is a simple demo that illustrates my question: https://funnyballoon.github.io/.

I am building a website whose data is based on randomly selected objects out of an array of JSON object ([Loading random objects from a huge (>200MB) array file without loading the entire array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709849/loading-random-objects-from-a-huge-200mb-array-file-without-loading-the-entir)), and I store that array as a static file hosted on Github. My website uses Angular. Now I am trying to use HTTP range request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) to achieve such random selection. This is the method I use:

```
  getPartialText(){
  let path:string='/mock/mockData.json';
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Range', 'bytes=0-123').set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
  this.http.get(path,{headers:headers, responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((data:any)=>{
    this.secondPartialText=data;
  });
}
```

Note here I set the bytes to '0-123', and this works perfectly, therefore it's (likely) not a CORS issue. However, when I set the start of the byte range to any number other than 0, for instance, 'bytes=1-123', I get an error with this message:

> Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

This is very confusing. Here is a simple demonstration of my website: https://funnyballoon.github.io/. As you can see, if you click the first button everything works just fine, whereas when you click the second button there's an error from the log.

Here is my code:

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public firstPartialText;
  public secondPartialText;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

  getFirstPartialText(){
      let path:string='/mock/mockData.json';
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Range', 'bytes=0-123').set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
      this.http.get(path,{headers:headers,responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.firstPartialText=data;
      });}

  getSecondPartialText(){
      let path:string='/mock/mockData.json';
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Range', 'bytes=1-123').set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
      this.http.get(path,{headers:headers, responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.secondPartialText=data;
  });}
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div> <button (click)="getFirstPartialText()">Get First</button>      
  {{firstPartialText}}</div>

<div> <button (click)="getSecondPartialText()">Get Second</button>     
  {{secondPartialText}}</div>
```

I appreciate if anybody can point out what is going wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: Github is accepting the range, but it's also sending the data gzipped, But it shouldn't do this if a range is requested.  So it's a bug with whatever GitHub is doing for ranged requests.. :(

Comment: @Keith Ahh OK Guess that is a bug on Github's part. It's weird though that when I use my computer's terminal to access it like ****       curl https://funnyballoon.github.io/mock/mockData.json -i -H "Range: bytes=1-123"   ****   It works but when I access it through browser it doesn't. Guess I should find another place to host my file... Thanks!

Comment: That is weird if curl works..  Im assuming its the gzip decoding were the error is, and maybe curl is more forgiving.  Another idea is maybe its the json decoding, have you tried renaming file to say txt and see if it works.?

Comment: @Keith Yeah I just renamed the json file to txt and changed the path but the results are still the same...